# Could an action potential produce few or more neurotransmitters based on the stimulus received?

Tags: neuroscience, neurotransmitter, neurophysiology, action-potential

I reckon that if you would be able to widen the AP width, it would produce more neurotransmitters in that larger time interval. Is that correct? Or does the neuron have a standard amount of neurotransmitters it releases in order to pass the signal post-synaptically?

(bonus: could it NOT result in neurotransmitter release, or does the definition of an AP include the release of neurotransmitters?)

Answer (score 6):

**Short answer**

- Widening of the action potential increases neurotransmitter release;
- Generally, an action potential results in the release of about one vesicle of  neurotranmitters;
- An action potential does not have to lead to neurotransmitter release - the chance being anywhere between 9 - 100%, depending on the synapse under investigation.

**Background**

Neurotransmitters are released in packets, called neurotransmitter **vesicles**:

[image: synaptic vesicles]
[<sup>Source: Science blogs</sup>](http://scienceblogs.com/purepedantry/2007/03/06/neuron-to-glia-synapse-on-axon/)

Vesicles are released via a mechanism involving Ca<sup>2+</sup>. When an action potential reaches the synaptic terminal, voltage-gated Ca<sup>2+</sup> channels open, which leads to Ca<sup>2+</sup> influx. The increased Ca<sup>2+</sup> in the terminal leads to release of vesicles.

A study by [Sabatini & Regehr (1997)](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/17/10/3425.full.pdf+html) showed that widening of the presynaptic action potential in rat cerebellar cells resulted in enhanced Ca<sup>2+</sup> influx, which in turn greatly enhanced neurotranmitter release.

According to a study in rat hippocampal cells it was shown that, on average, a single action potential releases approximately 0.5% of the vesicle pool from the presynaptic terminal. The presynaptic vesicle pool was estimated to be 100 - 200 vesicles, which hence **added up to 0.5 - 1 vesicle released per action potential** [(Ryan & Smith, 1995)](http://www.cell.com/neuron/abstract/0896-6273(95)90336-4?_returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2F0896627395903364%3Fshowall%3Dtrue).

An earlier study of [Rosenmund et al. (1993)](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/262/5134/754.short) confirms these findings in hippocampal neurons, and investigated the variability between different synapses in greater detail. They found that the chance that a single action potential released neurotranmitters was **9 - 54%**. They reasoned that larger synaptic terminals, or terminals triggered by long-term potentiation have a higher chance of releasing neurotransmitter. Moreover, such terminals with enhanced release probability may also have a higher chance of releasing **multiple vesicles per action potential**. They predicted that 54% of release events from such enhanced terminals may release multiple vesicles per action potentials, whereas just 9% of normal terminals may do this.

**References**
 **-** [Rosenmund et al. *Science* 1993; **262**: 754-6](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/262/5134/754.short)
 **-** [Ryan & Smith, *Neuron* 1995; **14**: 983-9](http://www.cell.com/neuron/abstract/0896-6273(95)90336-4?_returnURL=http%3A%2F%2Flinkinghub.elsevier.com%2Fretrieve%2Fpii%2F0896627395903364%3Fshowall%3Dtrue)
 **-** [Sabatini & Regehr, *J Neurosci* 1997; **17**: 3425-35](http://www.jneurosci.org/content/17/10/3425.full.pdf+html)

Answer (score 5):

Neurons encode the "largness" of the stimulus in firing frequency. Neurotransmitters are stored in vesicules near the end of the axon. It has been shown that neurotransmitter release follows Poisson-distribution and that usually a single "packet" (quantum) is released - this is known as quantal release. Although the actual number of molecules in a single vesicle vary a bit, and ocasionally multiple vesicles may be emptied, it is accepted that for a single AP a neuron releases a single vesicle. 
These two pages can give you more info and details:
http://neuroscience.uth.tmc.edu/s1/chapter04.html
http://neuroscience.uth.tmc.edu/s1/chapter05.html

Also this [link](http://advan.physiology.org/content/37/1/112) provides introductionary info on the topic

A great image from :http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1113/jphysiol.2006.123224/full

[image]

Comment: +1 for your answer. In an article (Ryan and Smith) I cited it was said that neuromuscular junctions released relatively small percentages of vesicles. Perhaps an interesting read?

Comment: I rather focused on the quantal nature of the release than actual release frequency, because in my opinion that is what the OP is interested in. I do not doubt that neurotransmitters are not necessarily released but **when** they are released it is done in a quantal manner. Also the graph shows that most of the time no release event occured that corresponds to what you've described.